# Proving that $X^+$, $X^-$, $\lvert X \rvert$ and $\text{sign}(X)$ are all measurable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I find this argument that $X^+$, $X^-$, $\lvert X \rvert$ and $\text{sign}(X)$ are all measurable, from *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course*, by Klenke, to be confusing:

[image]

[image]

I'm not saying it's wrong, but wouldn't it be much simpler to argue $X^+$ etc. is the composition of measurable maps and therefore measurable? I have done this below.

**My attempt:**

The functions $x \mapsto x^+$, $x \mapsto x^-$, $x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert$ and $x \mapsto \text{sign}(x)$ are unnamed in the textbook. I will name them $\mathrm{X^+} \colon \overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, $\mathrm{X}^- \colon \overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, $\lvert\mathrm{X}\rvert \colon \overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathrm{s} \colon \overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, respectively.
If we can show that they are measurable, then if $X \colon \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable, we conclude that $X^+ = \mathrm{X^+} \circ X \colon \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable, and similarly for $X^-$, $\lvert X \rvert$ and $\text{sign}(X)$.

Note that $\left\{ [-\infty, b) \colon b \in \mathbb{Q} \right\}$ is a generator for $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$.

1. If $b \leq 0$ then $(\mathrm{X}^+)^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = \emptyset \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. If $b > 0$ then $(\mathrm{X}^+)^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = [-\infty, b) \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$.
2. If $b \leq 0$ then $(\mathrm{X}^-)^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = \emptyset \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. If $b > 0$ then $(\mathrm{X}^-)^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = (-b, \infty] \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$.
3. If $b \leq 0$ then $\lvert \mathrm{X} \rvert^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = \emptyset \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. If $b > 0$ then $\lvert \mathrm{X} \rvert^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = (-b, b) \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$.
4. If $b < 1$ then $\mathrm{s}^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = \emptyset \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. If $b \in (-1, 0)$ then $\mathrm{s}^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = [-\infty, 0) \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. If $b \in [0, 1]$ then $\mathrm{s}^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = [-\infty, 0] \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. If $b > 1$ then $\mathrm{s}^{-1}\left([-\infty, b)\right) = \overline{\mathbb{R}} \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$.
   \end{enumerate}

Since all of $\mathrm{X^+}$, $\mathrm{X}^-$, $\lvert\mathrm{X}\rvert$ and $\mathrm{s}$ are measurable, we conclude that $X^+$, $X^-$, $\lvert X \rvert$ and $\text{sign}(X)$. are measurable.

Comment: "I'm not saying it's wrong, but wouldn't it be much simpler to argue X+ etc. is the composition of measurable maps and therefore measurable? I have done this below." but, this is not exactly what Klenke did?

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for the comment. I have been thinking about this more, and I think the key is what exactly is $\sigma(X_i \colon i \in I)$. If it's equal to $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ then maybe it works and is more elegant than what I did, but I don't immediately see it.

Comment: Even though your argument seems correct to me, you can simplify it a bit. For X+, X- and the absolute value, it is enough to note that they are continuous and thus measurable. The sign function is slightly more tricky, but it is enough to note (as shown in the book) that it is the sum of two indicator functions of measurable sets and therefore measurable as the sum of measurable functions.